# Showing a modal view controller from a tab bar app

Tags: iphone

First, I would like to warn that I am a complete newbie into iPhone coding...

I need to show up a viewcontroller from a library, I know that it is modal. I have a tab bar app (created with the default XCode template). I need to show that viewcontroller, there are no problem if it hides the tabbar itself... But I am quite clueless, I don't know even what to search, or what to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [presentModalViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW29) to display another `UIViewController` modally.

EDIT: If you want to display your modal view in response to a button touch (for example), you would display it like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    ModalViewController* controller = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

Then when you want to dismiss the modal controller, call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`. This can be called either on your main view controller, or the modal one.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know even what to search, or
>   what to read...

[View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good place to start to help you understand view controllers (including modal ones). If that's confusing, get a bigger picture with [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [start at the very beginning](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/_index.html).

Comment: Another place you might want to look is the documentation for the UITabBarDelegate Protocol. If you want something a bit "custom" to happen when a tab bar icon is selected, you will quite likely want to do that in the `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` callback

Answer (score 1):

You can call modal view as

```
YourViewController *yvc = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:YES]
[self presentModalViewController:yvc animated:YES];
```

You can call it in the `IBAction` method in case you want to call it on any control event like Button Click

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
     YourViewController *yvc = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:YES]
     [self presentModalViewController:yvc animated:YES];
}
```

You can call it using `self`.

Hope this helps you.

If you have more doubts on this then you can ask me.