# UIView or UIViewController for UIDatePicker and UIPickerView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I was wondering whether to use a full UIViewController or just a UIView to open a modal dialogue to pick a date and a language? As the pickers won't work inside a UIScrollView, I have to open them with a button. How would it work just with a UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use a UIViewController. Here is an SO question that may help - [Showing a modal view controller from a tab bar app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328777/showing-a-modal-view-controller-from-a-tab-bar-app).

Comment: Ok, I have it already like that, but was wondering if I can get rid of the whole controller for just a small view with one or two UI elements.